# CDN links for React packages and how to import it when using react using the scripts from CDN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, cdn

I was trying React without the NPM and other tools and instead using it by adding the CDN links,
but how to import the dependant packages, for example the useState hook? If it is added via another script tag, what is the CDN link for the same? below is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>React Local</title>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

   <script type="text/babel">
    const rootElement = document.getElementById('root') 

    const App = (props) => { 
    const [text, setText] = useState('hello'); 
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>{text}</h1>
            <input type="text" onClick={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}> </input>
            </div>
        );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here I will get error, useState is not defined.
**Note: This is just to test the React using the scripts from the CDN directly added in the html file, though i am aware of the create-react-app and the modern tools**

Comment: you might need more than those libraries for running React, also a more complex configuration.

Comment: the easiest way for running react is just running "npx create-react-app [name of your app]" command. https://create-react-app.dev/

Comment: I understand the usage of create-react-app and the bunch of modern tools, this is just to test the React in this simple single file while using their CDN which is also mentioned in the Reacts official page.

Comment: thank you for clarify your question to me. I started to investigate inside the packages you added and also looking at the documentation. Hooks are not included.

Comment: no problem, and thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When you use scripts, React is exposed on the window object as `React`, you also use a version of React which doesn't have hooks(hooks were released in 16.8)

Update your scripts to(you might want to use the development scripts for better error messages)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to access `useState` destructure it from `React` or use `React.useState`

Also, use `onChange` instead of `onClick` for input change events as well as using the `text` value from state as the `value` of the input

```js
<script type="text/babel">
  const { useState } = React

  const App = (props) => { 
    const [text, setText] = useState('hello');

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{text}</h1>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! after changing the react version it worked, you are right, hooks are part of React 16.8+.

Comment: How to destructure for other cdns ? I need `{ BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect, NavLink } from "react-router-dom"`. Is there a common way?

Comment: @ManirajSS add this script `<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
` and it will expose the package on `window.ReactRouterDOM` [see here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)