# Why is import React, ReactDOM not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

In my index.js page I have

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const page = (
    <div>
        <h1 className="header">This is JSX</h1>
        <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    </div>
)
console.log(page)
const container = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    page,
    container
);
```

In my index.html I'm having

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script> -->

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Im not getting the elements rendered in my localhost.
It works if I uncomment
`<!-- <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script> <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script> <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script> -->` 
and remove my imports.

Please help check in this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CDN links for React packages and how to import it when using react using the scripts from CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834741/cdn-links-for-react-packages-and-how-to-import-it-when-using-react-using-the-scr)

Comment: when using script tag you dont use `import React from "react";`. That is trying to import from node_modules

Comment: What version of React are you using. v18 [uses a different "create root" method](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to use React as a UMD with [Babel standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-standalone) and without any bundle tools like Webpack, Rollup, and Vite.

A working example using `react@16.14.0`

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.14.0/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.14.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`script.js`:

```js
const Page = () => (
  <div>
    <h1 className="header">This is JSX</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
);

const container = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<Page />, container);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-droxjo?file=script.js)